# Failed argument deduction in views::take_while

Tags: c++, c++20

I have this code:

```
for (auto e : foo | ::std::views::take_while([](const char* x) { return x != nullptr; }))
      std::cout << e << "\n";
```

All is fine and dandy, but this lambda is a tat long and unwieldy. Since it occurs many times, I decide to have a named function object instead.

```
class non_null                                    
{ 
    template <typename T> bool operator()(const T* t) {
            return t != nullptr;
    }
};

for (auto e : foo | ::std::views::take_while(non_null()))
      std::cout << e << "\n";
```

This fails to compile with a bucketful of error messages, with a "class template argument deduction failed" on top.

Why, and what can be done about it? (Except calling `take_while` with a non-templated predicate, which obviously works).

Comment: What happens if you use `non_null{}` instead of `non_null()`?  `non_null()` might be a most vexing parse issue.

Comment: Why not just `bool operator()(void const* t){ return t != nullptr; }`?

Comment: Typo: It's definitely not going to work if `operator()` is private! Still broken if I replace `class` with `struct`, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::views::take_while` needs the call operator of the object being passed to it to be const-qualified in order for deduction to succeed:

```
struct non_null                                    
{ 
    template <typename T> 
    bool operator()(const T* t) const {  // <-- const-qualified
            return t != nullptr;
    }
};
```

However, if you just want to name the predicate, you could simply do:

```
auto non_null = [](const auto* x) { return x != nullptr; };
```

and use it like this:

```
for (auto e : foo | ::std::views::take_while(non_null))
      std::cout << e << "\n";
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M67PP6).

Comment: [Relevant portion of standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.take.while#sentinel-3). The `take_while_range<V, non_null>::sentinel` returned by `end` ends up referring to the `non_null` through a `non_null const*` (all expo-only, ofc), and the `operator==` between the iterators and the end sentinel thus needs `non_null::operator()` to take `*this` as `const`.